# REPL signal for completion of a computation

Tags: python

I am building a web interface to a Python interpreter. Is there an accepted way to interact with an interpreter so that it can signal that a computation is complete?

For example:

```
>>> 1+1
2
>>>
```

Other than checking for `>>>`, how can I know that the interpreter has completed its evaluation of the given expression?

Comment: I'd not interface an actual interpreter there. I'd emulate that instead; I'd pass `'single'` to the [`compile()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile)..

Comment: Ah, interesting. But let's say I want to generalize my code to interact with different types of interpreters. For example, right now I support both Python and R.

Comment: I'd still stick to wrapping the Python code; you cannot reliably look for the `>>>`. Code you run can change the prompt, or write to stdout and thoroughly mess stuff up.